# Cannot connect to windev HFSQL db using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc, windev

```
import pyodbc 
print('work')
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={HFSQL};Server Name=127.0.0.1;Server Port=4900;Database=main;UID=admin;PWD=admin", autocommit=True) 
print('not work')
conn.close()
```

I followed instraction https://doc.windev.com/en-US/?3044179&3044179&verdisp=150
And but i can't connect.
Else if you now how to open .fic/.ndx files it will do my life more easy.

Comment: The instructions you cited explain how to set up an ODBC DSN. Did you try that approach?

Comment: I have never used HFSQL. Try to connect to some other type of database like sql or sqlite.
This problem can be caused by different things. 
Try connecting sqlite because this is the fastest and simplest way to connect.

apt install libsqliteodbc
then
pyodbc.connect("Driver=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=sqlite.db")

Comment: Emm... Connection to another db - was fine.